# Multimethods performance

Tags: clojure

What's the performance hit of using multi methods? If I have 2 functions with the same name, and the same number of arguments that differ only by the type (list vs. int), is my performance going to suffer much?

In other words, it it better to name my vector adding function: "add-vector" or leave it as "add" or possibly "+"?

(For the sake of simplicity let's ignore the problems I may have re-defining built-in functions like "+").

Comment: I would answer instead of the comment, but as it doesn't relate to clojure in specific, multimethods should not incur any additional penalty than normal lookups. That is, one implementation stratengy is to mangle names encoding them with argument types, and then there should be no overhead. However, the implementation strategy Clojure uses is unknown to me, but if it uses the above mechanism, there will be no additional overhead.

Comment: Yeah, since clojure is a dynamic language I don't think it will be the same. Also clojure uses a dispatch function which generates keys that are applied to a list of available functions.

Comment: You might want to look into `clojure.contrib.generic` and `clojure.contrib.generic.*` (`c.c.generic.arithmetic` will likely be most interesting to you).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a performance cost to using multi-methods, but unless absolutely necessary, you should continue to use them if they're the best abstraction.

That said, Clojure 1.2's [protocols](http://clojure.org/protocols) provide a native-speed alternative to multi-methods for certain use cases, and are particularly suited to cases where one might formerly have used a multi-method with a type-based dispatch.

Comment: Excellent, I think this is exactly what I'm looking for. Protocols should allow me to "override" the + function for my vector classes.

Answer (score 1):

Since Clojure can use arbitrary dispatch functions the additional cost of a multimethod is the cost of the dispatch function + a map lookup.

Or as cemerick put it:

```
(defmulti can-your-dispatch-do-that?
  (fn [& _]
    (if (= (phase-of-moon) :full)
      :do-this
      :do-that)))
```